# how to connect app using json

Tags: android, json, gridview

I am trying to connect my app using `json` but when I run my app it gets crashed. I think the problem is in the following code:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to download Movies", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        JSONObject jsono = null;


        // gridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.main_gridview);
        ArrayList<Movie> l = new ArrayList<>();
        try 
        {
            jsono = new JSONObject((java.util.Map) result);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                String posterPath = object.getString("poster_path");
                String title = object.getString("original_title");
                String id = object.getString("id");
                Movie m = new Movie(id, title, posterPath);
                l.add(m);
            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(MainActivity.this, result);

    }
```

Someone kindly help me.

Comment: Copy the crash from logcat

Answer (score 0):

```
jsono = new JSONObject((java.util.Map) result);
```

Cast ArrayList to Map?

I think that you should read more basic knowledge about casting types in java, Maps, ArrayList and JSON.